# How plot a pie chart colored with one scaled color and using plotly package

Tags: r

I have this sample data frame :

```
> Data
                    Produits Pourcentages
1              Crème de jour        27.10
2                      sérum        14.50
3              Crème de nuit        13.80
4                     masque         8.82
5      démaquillant à rincer         7.73
6  démaquillant sans rincage         7.24
7                     lotion         6.57
8                eau florale         5.83
9                      huile         5.65
10          produits teintés         2.82
```

Then, I want to plot a pie chart using only the `plotly` package.

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

p <- plot_ly(Data, labels = ~Produits, values = ~Pourcentages, type = 'pie') %>%
  layout(title = 'United States Personal Expenditures by Categories in 1960',
         xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
         yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE))
```

It gives me this pie chart:

[image]

But I don't need to get many colors, I just need one scaled color which has an intensity that increases in function of the variable  `Pourcentages`.

In another word, I want a pie chart using `plotly` package like this:

[image]

Thank you for your help !

Comment: something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50625970/plotly-create-pie-chart-with-continuous-color-scale?rq=1

Comment: @RonakShah, no it si not the same because in that example it has many colors (red,green...). I need one color

Comment: @RonakShah, no it is not because I need to use only color, but in your example there is many color (red,green...)

Comment: There are very rare chances that you will get question exactly same as yours. You need to adapt the similar answers which are available according to your need as shown in the answer by @symbolrush

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's another solution expanding the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50625970/plotly-create-pie-chart-with-continuous-color-scale?rq=1):

```
Data <- data.frame(
  Produits = c("Crème de jour", "sérum", "Crème de nuit", "masque", "démaquillant à rincer", "démaquillant sans rincage", "lotion", "eau florale", "huile", "produits teintés"),
  Pourcentages = c(27.10, 14.50, 13.80, 8.82, 7.73, 7.24, 6.57, 5.83, 5.65, 2.82)
)
gradient <- colorRampPalette(c('lightblue', 'darkblue'))
Data$colors <- gradient(dim(Data)[1])[as.numeric(cut(Data$Pourcentages, breaks = dim(Data)[1]))]
plot_ly(Data, labels = ~Produits, values = ~Pourcentages, type = 'pie', marker = list(colors = ~colors))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
# Demo data:
Data <- data.frame(Produits = letters[1:5], Pourcentages = (1:5)/15)

# List of colors:
library(RColorBrewer)
colors = colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9, "Blues"))(100)[100*Data$Pourcentages]

# Chart:
p <- plot_ly(Data, labels = ~Produits, values = ~Pourcentages, type = 'pie',
             marker = list(colors = colors)) %>%
  layout(title = 'United States Personal Expenditures by Categories in 1960',
         xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
         yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
         showlegend = TRUE)
p
```

[image]

Comment: Antonio Roldan Diaz, thank you but it is not the same data frame so it doesn't give the need result. I invite you to remplace your dataframe `Data <- data.frame(Produits = letters[1:5], Pourcentages = (1:5)/15)` by `Data<-data.frame(Produits,Pourcentages)` and you will see the difference

Comment: This is an example, you can change colors and percentages and it keeps working, I have tried with your data and it looks good, but the percentages of my example go from 0 to 1 and yours from 0 to 100, that's why I multiply by 100 when selecting the colors and you should modify that part (`colorRampPalette (brewer.pal (9," Blues ")) (100) [Data $ Pourcentages]`).

Answer (score 1):

more simple solution :

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

##
Produits<-c("Crème de jour","sérum","Crème de nuit","masque","démaquillant à rincer",
            "démaquillant sans rincage","lotion","eau florale","huile","produits teintés")
Pourcentages<-c(27.1,14.5,13.8,8.82,7.73,7.24,6.57,5.83,5.65,2.82)
colors<-c("#ff0000","#ff1919","#ff3232","#ff4c4c","#ff6666",
          "#ff7f7f","#ff9999","#ffb2b2","#ffcccc","#ffe5e5")

Data<-data.frame(Produits,Pourcentages,colors)


plot_ly(Data, labels = ~Produits, values = ~Pourcentages, type = 'pie', marker = list(colors = ~colors))%>%
  layout(title = 'Les pourcentages des types de soins préférés',
         xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
         yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
         showlegend = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks mate ! for bar chart is there a similar solution ?